# -webkit-filter won't properly work in an Android cordova app

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova

Funny thing. Imagine you have a `div` with a class called `night-mode` and this css roaming around:

```
.night-mode.night-mode-enabled {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(80%);
}
```

Hitting a button you turn on this really cheap *night mode* in the app, but toggling the class `night-mode-enabled` to those important `div`s.

Prepare, compile, run in iOS and it works as expected. **Everything** inside the div goes on a darker mode, keeping the same colors but unsaturating them a little bit.

Running in Android, though... Apart from being **extra** slow (I wouldn't consider a Note 3 to be a particularly slow phone), it doesn't really do anything to that div. Then, I start juggling with other rule combinations like these fancy ones:

```
.night-mode.night-mode-enabled, 
.night-mode.night-mode-enabled>div *, 
.night-mode.night-mode-enabled * {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(80%);
}
```

This gets the job *almost* done. By almost I mean, it's able to invert everything but the items that fall in some cases (my bet is *"in an even amount of ascendants until `.night-mode.night-mode-enabled`"*) are not applied.

Could it be somehow related to my cordova for Android being fairly old (3.7.1) and the iOS one being a little bit newer (3.8.0)?

*Note: Before anyone tells me I need to upgrade cordova because of the new Play Store requirements, I have to admit it's something in my pipeline for the following month, but it's too much time consuming to do it for the following release, so if the filter is something fixable by cordova upgrade, fine, but if avoidable, it would be much much nicer.*

Comment: One reason could be the version of webkit your device is using. The version is depending of the android version AND the producer of the device. In the past I had similiair trouble with a Samsung device, they used another version instead of the corresponding android version.

Comment: @Joerg that would clarify a lot. Despite the phone is a lollipop, yeah, that could be the thing. I'll try it with a lenovo and tell you later

Comment: Sadly, same result, @Joerg. It might be a huge coincidence, but despite that Lenovo being in the _filter constraints_ (using prefix, +4.4) seems not to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for your filter problem, but when I had a similar problem, I injected in the body some classes to have CSS selectors. I used the device plugin and created this code to fetch Android 4.4 (just change it to your needs):

```
function onDeviceReady() {
   if (device.platform === "Android") {
      var tmp = device.version.split(".");
      if (parseFloat(tmp[0] + "." + tmp[1]) === 4.4){
         $("body").addClass("API18");
      }
   }
}
```

If you need a deeper device model detection, just inject the device model from the plugin.

If you need to detect iOS models by name, you can use this list: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models For Android you can find some models here http://download.cyanogenmod.org